# Swagger models Option[Int] to Object while Option[String] is modelled correctly as string

Tags: scala, swagger

I have the following case class

```
@ApiModel("StationResponse") case class StationResponse (id: Option[String],
                            @ApiModelProperty(dataType = "double", required = false)
                            longitude: Option[Double])
```

The longitude field is modelled as "Object" instead of "double"

I tried to override the dataType with @ApiModelProperty but no luck. Thanks for your comments.

I am using Swagger 1.3.12 with Scala 2.11.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding @field annotation along with ApiModelProperty like below:

```
@ApiModel("StationResponse") 
case class StationResponse (id: Option[String],
                            @(ApiModelProperty@field)(dataType = "double", required = false)
                            longitude: Option[Double])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's now a bit simpler:

```
@ApiModelProperty(dataType = "Long") timingId: Option[Long]
```

workes just fine for me with: `"io.swagger" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.6.0"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Springfox - per the [documentation](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#overriding-property-datatypes) you can do the following:

```
@ApiModel("StationResponse") 
case class StationResponse (id: Option[String], longitude: Option[Double]) {

  @ApiModelProperty(dataType = "double", required = false)
  def getLongitude: Option[Double] = longitude

}
```

Might be worth a shot on other Swagger generation libs